# Backend menus not showing for a new user

Tags: joomla-3.x, acl

I've created a new access level for my Joomla 3.3 website, because I need to allow users to login into the backend and create/modify articles and some components.

I've followed this tutorial: http://bectin.com/random-insights/joomla/79-using-access-control-lists-acl-to-limit-back-end-access-to-a-single-component, but it isn't working correctly.

I can login with the new user to the backend, but it doesn't appear any menu item. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing ACL changes, sometimes **logging out**, **clearing caches** and **cookies** and then **logging-in** again resolves such issues.

In your specific case, after reading the instructions on the link your provided, it is also possible that you might have missed the part where you must go to each component you want to allow access and set the proper **Permissions** in its **Configuration** (Options button).

E.g. You want to allow access to the **Content Component**: In the permissions you should allow access to the "**Access Administration Interface**", which handles the Admin Menu access and the backend admin interface of the component.

As a further recommendation: **Do not allow** :**Delete** and **Configure** for this usergroup.

As for a more customized administration navigation, there are [**3rd party extensions**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-navigation) that will let you create custom menus specific for usergroups with more flexibility.

I use a lot the [**Admin Menu Manager Pro**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-navigation/22805) in conjunction with [**Access Manager**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control/19766).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've "fixed" it: after reconnecting (logout & login) to the admin interface, all worked fine.

Comment: Just show your comment - I was improving my answer, including the suggestion of logout/login. Glad you found your away around.

Comment: Refresh worked for me; thanks for linking the tutorial, had some trouble finding something similar